# How do i get Items from localstorage and render it to my list?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to create a Todo list with two values called "Title" and "Detail".
So far I am able to set items in my local storage, but not sure how do I get the items back from the same local storage and render it on the list.

Here is my TaskContext.js component:

```
import React, { createContext, useState, useEffect } from "react";
import uuid from "uuid/v1";

export const TaskContext = createContext();

const TaskContextProvider = props => {
  const [tasks, setTasks] = useState([
    { title: "name of the wind", detail: "patrick", id: 1 },
    { title: "Rich dad poor dad", detail: "wilson", id: 2 }
  ]);

  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem("tasks", JSON.stringify(tasks));
  }, [tasks]);

  const addTask = (title, detail) => {
    setTasks([...tasks, { title: title, detail: detail, id: uuid() }]);
  };

  const removeTask = id => {
    setTasks(tasks.filter(task => task.id !== id));
  };

  return (
    <TaskContext.Provider value={{ tasks, addTask, removeTask }}>
      {props.children}
    </TaskContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default TaskContextProvider;
```

Help me out please.

Comment: Use localStorage.getItem('itemKey'). See here for reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `localStorage.getItem("tasks")` inside the hook to retrieve the data from localStorage.

**Example**

```
const SomeComponent = props => {
  const [tasks, setTasks] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    let taskList = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("tasks")); // get the data
    if(taskList)  {
      setTasks(taskList); // update the state if taskList has data
    }
  }, []);



  return (
    /** Print your task here */
  );
};

export default SomeComponent;
```

Comment: It does the job, Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
localStorage.getItem("tasks")
```

Put this in a variable and `JSON.parse()` it.

Comment: Sure but a little more descriptive please, Do I need to put ti inside use effect hook?

Answer (score 0):

1. Items you save in localStorage are store in Json format.
2. localStorage has methods used to access its store for basic CRUD activities e.g:

   - `localStorage.setItem(key: JSON.stringify(value))` which you used, in this case, to save the item to localStorage
   - `JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(key))` to get the item stored by the key, you need to convert it to a normal object in this case from JSON, hence the need for the JSON.parse()
   - `localStorage.clear()` to clear all items in localStorage
   - `localStorage.removeItem(key)` to remove an item from localStorage by the item key

`const theTasks = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('tasks'));`

Comment: Where do I need to put this? Inside some hook or what?

Comment: It depends on what exactly you're trying to do @abhinavAnshul

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.